# Firebase Crashlytics: what is meaning of "RAM free" size in firebase Crashlytics for crashes?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

**Firebase Crashlytics : What is meaning of "RAM free" size in firebase Crashlytics crashes details??**

- Its like remaining RAM of system at time of crash ??
- or its remaining RAM of app allotted size only

Thank You in advance.

[image: for ref]